# How to find and replace product title using sql query

Tags: product, database, sql, query

I am having a magento store with English and Arabic language store view. 
I am having more than **5000 products**(`both simple & configuable products`). All the products starts from Style now i want to modify the text "Style" into "Model"

Same as well as for **Arabic language store view**.

I want to know, how to find the product title and replace my required text using sql query.

Answer (score 1):

In ,default magento product details *page title has been set from* ***meta_title  attribute***.

This attribute is a **varchar** attribute and it attribute code can be found at eav_attribute.

> ```
> select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'meta_title' and entity_type_id =4
> ```

As this a varchar attribute then it value, *is saved* **catalog_product_entity_varchar** table.

So, ***you need to run your query at  this table***

---

### Query

> ```
> UPDATE value 
> SET    value = Replace(url, 'Style', 'Model') 
> WHERE  attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id 
>                        FROM   eav_attribute 
>                        WHERE  attribute_code = 'meta_title' 
>                               AND entity_type_id = 4) 
>        AND store_id = your_store_id
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking other route to bulk product update.

Take a look at [inventory-import-export](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-import-export.html), which gives you more control, you can test with few records to see if you changes are being reflected or before doing it for all of them.

If you are experienced with sql stuff, go for above solution (I didn't test and assume it works fine).